# How to calculate the resolution of a segment of a 360° sphere?

Tags: geometry

Sorry if this is a bit off-topic. There are several cameras that shoot full 360° spherical photos.

The output of a spherical video is 6,144 x 3,160, or 19.4 megapixels spread out over the entire sphere (the software projects this 2:1 flat image over a sphere).

If I take a segment of that 360° sphere, say, one with a field of view of 93.3° x 70.4° (a typical 17mm rectilinear camera lens in 4:3 aspect) what will be the resulting resolution in pixel dimensions of that segment?

My thinking is that the overall field of view of the entire 360° photo is essentially 360° x 180°, so a photo that's 93.3° x 70.4° is:

(93.3/360) x (70.4/180)

26% x 39% of the entire 360° field of view.

6,144(0.26) x 3,160(0.39) = 1,597 x 1,232

or roughly 2 megapixels.

Is this methodology correct?

Comment: Are the pixels uniformly distributed over the sphere, or are there areas with higher resolution than others?

Comment: Whatever way they map a sphere to a $2:1$ flat image, there has to be a lot of distortion. The part of the image occupied by your $17$ mm-lens-equivalent image will depend on how that distortion is managed, and probably on which part of the image you decide to view through that $17$ mm "lens". I don't think this question is answerable with the given information.